# RSA calculate $d$ using Chinese Remainder Theorem with $d_p$, $d_q$ and $e$

Tags: rsa, modular-arithmetic, prime-numbers, attack, number-theory

Suppose for a RSA system I have the following variables given: 
modulus $n$, expononent $e$, $d_p$ and $d_q$
Where, $d_p = d\bmod(p-1)$ and $d_q = d\bmod(q-1)$,
Is it possible to find the private exponent $d$ ?
Note: $p$, $q$, $p-1$ and $q-1$ are not known

Comment: Hint: it holds that $e\,d_p\equiv1\bmod(p-1)$.

Comment: I understand that, but I can't figure out where to use it

Comment: I see an approach if $e$ is small: there exist $a\le e$ with $e\,d_p=a\,(p-1)+1$, and there's an easy test to determine if we found it.

Comment: e is the standard 65537

Comment: Then find how you find $a$, then find $a$, then you are done! I forecast a runtime in seconds.

Comment: wouldn't i require (p-1) for that? If you're talking about something else, could you please name the method? Thanks

Comment: No the method does not require knowledge of $p-1$. The method has no name, because $d_p$ normally is secret. The idea is that there is a narrow choice of $a$ (at most $e$ possible values), a quick way to weed out most candidates $a$ (since $a$ is a small divisor of $e\,d_p-1$), and when that holds an easy test to confirm or infirm the guess of $a$, which I let you find.

Comment: Thank you, I finally got the solution. I iterated k over the range or e and the checking condition was as follows : `math.gcd(65537, p1) == 1 and isprime(p1+1) == True and n % (p1+1) == 0`

Comment: That method works fine in the small $e$ case,  For large $e$, you could compute $\gcd( r^{e \cdot d_p} - r, n)$ for random $r$, this is (with good probability) $p$.

Comment: @poncho: you should make an answer with that one, it is much cleaner, and I had missed it.